# Can you split out datetime months in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to create new columns representing the individual months comprising the delta between two datetimes? The output would likely be binary values for each new monthly column. Am thinking something like this (which doesn't work):

```
for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    i_name = str(i)
    values = example['end'] - example['start'] #Example line - need to expose values here) 
    example[i_name] = values
```

To go from this:

```
    end         name        start
0   28/02/2012  joe bloggs  01/01/2012
1   15/03/2012  jane bloggs 01/02/2012
2   17/05/2012  jim bloggs  01/04/2012
3   18/04/2012  john bloggs 01/02/2012
```

To this:

```
    end         1   2   3   4   5   name        start
0   28/02/2012  1   1   0   0   0   joe bloggs  01/01/2012
1   15/03/2012  0   1   1   0   0   jane bloggs 01/02/2012
2   17/05/2012  0   0   0   1   1   jim bloggs  01/04/2012
3   18/04/2012  0   1   1   1   0   john bloggs 01/02/2012
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use mainly [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
#convert columns to datetime
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df.end, dayfirst=True)
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df.start, dayfirst=True)
#print df

#get months to Series
end = df['end'].dt.month
start = df['start'].dt.month

#create difference DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'end':end, 'start':start})
        .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(range(x.start, x.end + 1)), axis=1)
print df1
     0    1    2
0  1.0  2.0  NaN
1  2.0  3.0  NaN
2  4.0  5.0  NaN
3  2.0  3.0  4.0

#create indicator variables, sum values by index
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df1.stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)) 
        .groupby(level=0).sum().astype(int)

#convert float columns names to int
df1.columns = df1.columns.to_series().astype(int)
print df1
   1  2  3  4  5
0  1  1  0  0  0
1  0  1  1  0  0
2  0  0  0  1  1
3  0  1  1  1  0
```

```
#append to original DataFrame
print pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
         end         name      start  1  2  3  4  5
0 2012-02-28   joe bloggs 2012-01-01  1  1  0  0  0
1 2012-03-15  jane bloggs 2012-02-01  0  1  1  0  0
2 2012-05-17   jim bloggs 2012-04-01  0  0  0  1  1
3 2012-04-18  john bloggs 2012-02-01  0  1  1  1  0
```

Comment: Yeah that's a bit cleaner than my solution

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```
example = pd.read_csv(FILE, parse_dates=[0, 2], dayfirst=True)
for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    i_name = str(i)
    example[i_name] = example.apply(lambda example: example["start"] <= pd.datetime(2012, i, 1) <= example["end"], axis=1).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to convert the date columns to datetime with `pd.to_datetime` as such:

```
import pandas as pd
example['end'] = pd.to_datetime(example['end'], dayfirst=True) #default is ydm...
example['start'] = pd.to_datetime(example['start'], dayfirst=True)
```

then in your for-loop you can just set the appropriate values as such:

```
example[str(i)] = 0
example[str(i)][( i >= example['start'].dt.month) & (example['end'].dt.month >= i)] = 1
```

(stealing the `dt.month` from jezrael's answer) which results in:

```
import pandas as pd
example['end'] = pd.to_datetime(example['end'], dayfirst=True) #default is ydm...
example['start'] = pd.to_datetime(example['start'], dayfirst=True)

for i in range(1,13):
  example[str(i)] = 0
  example[str(i)][( i >= example['start'].dt.month) & (example['end'].dt.month >= i)] = 1
```

This then results in:

```
In[101]: example
Out[101]: 
         end         name      start  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12
0 2012-02-28   joe bloggs 2012-01-01  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0
1 2012-03-15  jane bloggs 2012-02-01  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0
2 2012-05-17   jim bloggs 2012-04-01  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0   0   0   0
3 2012-04-18  john bloggs 2012-02-01  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0
```